Find /dev/mediaX entry corresponding to /dev/videoY using ioctl:s
Given a /dev/videoX V4L2 node, I can find the corresponding Media API /dev/mediaY by searching for subdirectories named media* in /sys/class/video4linux/videoX/device/.
Are there any way to get the name of the media node using ioctl:s on the /dev/videoX node, without having to search the sysfs?
